# hplip not working on fresh Ubuntu 20.04 installation

Tags: apt, 20.04, hplip

I have just done a clean installation of Ubuntu 20.04.1 on a Lenovo Yoga 730. I have a wireless HP Photosmart C4780 which I have setup successfully setup on another Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 18.04 machine by simply using

```
hp-setup 192.168.0.22
```

When I first logged in to the new installation I used

```
apt list --installed
```

which showed me that hplip and hplip-data were installed. I ran

```
apt install hplip-gui
```

and then tried

```
hp-setup 192.168.0.22
```

which fails with error

```
error:  Printer queue setup failed.   Error : successful-ok-ignored-or-substituted-attributes
```

To check what is wrong I ran

```
hp-doctor
```

which gives

```
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.20.3)
Self Diagnse Utility and Healing Utility ver. 1.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.


HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.20.3)
Self Diagnse Utility and Healing Utility ver. 1.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

 

Checking for Deprecated items....
No Deprecated items are found


Checking for HPLIP updates....
error: Failed to locate hp-upgrade utility


Checking for Dependencies....
warning: ubuntu-20.04 version is not supported. Using ubuntu-19.10 versions dependencies to verify and install...

---------------
| SYSTEM INFO |
---------------

 Kernel: 5.4.0-48-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 10 10:58:49 UTC 2020 GNU/Linux
 Host: nell
 Proc: 5.4.0-48-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 10 10:58:49 UTC 2020 GNU/Linux
 Distribution: ubuntu 20.04
 Bitness: 64 bit


-----------------------
| HPLIP CONFIGURATION |
-----------------------

HPLIP-Version: HPLIP 3.20.3
HPLIP-Home: /usr/share/hplip
warning: HPLIP-Installation: Auto installation is not supported for ubuntu distro  20.04 version 

Current contents of '/etc/hp/hplip.conf' file:
# hplip.conf.  Generated from hplip.conf.in by configure.

[hplip]
version=3.20.3

[dirs]
home=/usr/share/hplip
run=/var/run
ppd=/usr/share/ppd/hplip/HP
ppdbase=/usr/share/ppd/hplip
doc=/usr/share/doc/hplip
html=/usr/share/doc/hplip-doc
icon=no
cupsbackend=/usr/lib/cups/backend
cupsfilter=/usr/lib/cups/filter
drv=/usr/share/cups/drv
bin=/usr/bin
apparmor=/etc/apparmor.d
# Following values are determined at configure time and cannot be changed.
[configure]
network-build=yes
libusb01-build=no
pp-build=no
gui-build=yes
scanner-build=yes
fax-build=yes
dbus-build=yes
cups11-build=no
doc-build=yes
shadow-build=no
hpijs-install=yes
foomatic-drv-install=yes
foomatic-ppd-install=no
foomatic-rip-hplip-install=no
hpcups-install=yes
cups-drv-install=yes
cups-ppd-install=no
internal-tag=3.20.3
restricted-build=no
ui-toolkit=qt5
qt3=no
qt4=no
qt5=yes
policy-kit=yes
lite-build=no
udev_sysfs_rules=no
hpcups-only-build=no
hpijs-only-build=no
apparmor_build=no
class-driver=no


Current contents of '/var/lib/hp/hplip.state' file:
[plugin]
installed = 1
eula = 1
version = 3.20.3



Current contents of '~/.hplip/hplip.conf' file:
[last_used]
device_uri = hp:/net/Photosmart_C4700_series?ip=192.168.0.22

[installation]
date_time = 09/22/20 18:30:55
version = 3.20.3


 <Package-name>        <Package-Desc>      <Required/Optional> <Min-Version> <Installed-Version> <Status>   <Comment>

-------------------------
| External Dependencies |
-------------------------

 error: cups          CUPS - Common Unix Printing System                           REQUIRED        1.1             -               INCOMPAT   'CUPS may not be installed or not running'
 gs                   GhostScript - PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer REQUIRED        7.05            9.50            OK         -
 error: xsane         xsane - Graphical scanner frontend for SANE                  OPTIONAL        0.9             -               MISSING    'xsane needs to be installed'
 scanimage            scanimage - Shell scanning program                           OPTIONAL        1.0             1.0.29          OK         -
 error: dbus          DBus - Message bus system                                    REQUIRED        -               1.12.16         MISSING    'DBUS may not be installed or not running'
 policykit            PolicyKit - Administrative policy framework                  OPTIONAL        -               0.105           OK         -
 network              network -wget                                                OPTIONAL        -               1.20.3          OK         -
 avahi-utils          avahi-utils                                                  OPTIONAL        -               0.7             OK         -

------------------------
| General Dependencies |
------------------------

 error: libjpeg       libjpeg - JPEG library                                       REQUIRED        -               -               MISSING    'libjpeg needs to be installed'
 error: cups-devel    CUPS devel- Common Unix Printing System development files    REQUIRED        -               -               MISSING    'cups-devel needs to be installed'
 error: cups-image    CUPS image - CUPS image development files                    REQUIRED        -               -               MISSING    'cups-image needs to be installed'
 error: libpthread    libpthread - POSIX threads library                           REQUIRED        -               b'2.31'         MISSING    'libpthread needs to be installed'
 error: libusb        libusb - USB library                                         REQUIRED        -               1.0             MISSING    'libusb needs to be installed'
 sane                 SANE - Scanning library                                      REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 error: sane-devel    SANE - Scanning library development files                    REQUIRED        -               -               MISSING    'sane-devel needs to be installed'
 error: libnetsnmp-devel libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files REQUIRED        5.0.9           -               MISSING    'libnetsnmp-devel needs to be installed'
 error: libcrypto     libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptographic library                    REQUIRED        -               1.1.1           MISSING    'libcrypto needs to be installed'
 python3X             Python 2.2 or greater - Python programming language          REQUIRED        2.2             3.8.2           OK         -
 python3-notify2      Python libnotify - Python bindings for the libnotify Desktop notifications OPTIONAL        -               -               OK         -
 error: python3-pyqt4-dbus PyQt 4 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt4                         OPTIONAL        4.0             -               MISSING    'python3-pyqt4-dbus needs to be installed'
 error: python3-pyqt4 PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x)         REQUIRED        4.0             -               MISSING    'python3-pyqt4 needs to be installed'
 python3-dbus         Python DBus - Python bindings for DBus                       REQUIRED        0.80.0          1.2.16          OK         -
 python3-xml          Python XML libraries                                         REQUIRED        -               2.2.9           OK         -
 error: python3-devel Python devel - Python development files                      REQUIRED        2.2             3.8.2           MISSING    'python3-devel needs to be installed'
 python3-pil          PIL - Python Imaging Library (required for commandline scanning with hp-scan) OPTIONAL        -               7.0.0           OK         -
 python3-reportlab    Reportlab - PDF library for Python                           OPTIONAL        2.0             3.5.34          OK         -

--------------
| COMPILEDEP |
--------------

 error: libtool       libtool - Library building support services                  REQUIRED        -               -               MISSING    'libtool needs to be installed'
 error: gcc           gcc - GNU Project C and C++ Compiler                         REQUIRED        -               -               MISSING    'gcc needs to be installed'
 error: make          make - GNU make utility to maintain groups of programs       REQUIRED        3.0             -               MISSING    'make needs to be installed'

---------------------
| Python Extentions |
---------------------

 cupsext              CUPS-Extension                                               REQUIRED        -               3.20.3          OK         -
 hpmudext             IO-Extension                                                 REQUIRED        -               3.20.3          OK         -

----------------------
| Scan Configuration |
----------------------

'/etc/sane.d/dll.d/hpaio' not found.
 hpaio                HPLIP-SANE-Backend                                           REQUIRED        -               3.20.3          OK         'hpaio found in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf'
 scanext              Scan-SANE-Extension                                          REQUIRED        -               3.20.3          OK         -

------------------------------
| DISCOVERED SCANNER DEVICES |
------------------------------

No Scanner found.

--------------------------
| DISCOVERED USB DEVICES |
--------------------------

No devices found.

---------------------------------
| INSTALLED CUPS PRINTER QUEUES |
---------------------------------

 
lpstat
------
Type: Unknown
Device URI: No destinations added.


--------------
| PERMISSION |
--------------

Missing Required Dependencies
-----------------------------
error: 'libcups2' package is missing or 'cups' service is not running.
error: 'libdbus-1-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libjpeg-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libcups2-dev' package is missing or 'cups' service is not running.
error: 'cups-bsd' package is missing or 'cups' service is not running.
error: 'cups-client' package is missing or 'cups' service is not running.
error: 'libcupsimage2-dev' package is missing or 'cups' service is not running.
error: 'build-essential' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libusb-1.0.0-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libusb-0.1-4' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libsane-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libsnmp-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'snmp-mibs-downloader' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'openssl' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'python3-pyqt4' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'gtk2-engines-pixbuf' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'python3-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libtool' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libtool-bin' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'build-essential' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'build-essential' package is missing/incompatible 
Missing Optional Dependencies
-----------------------------
error: 'gtk2-engines-pixbuf' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'xsane' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'python3-dbus.mainloop.qt' package is missing/incompatible 


ENTER SUDO PASSWORD
-------------------
Please enter the sudoer password: 
 

Checking Permissions....


Checking for Configured Queues....
No Queue added

warning: No Queue(s) configured.


Checking for HP Properitery Plugin's....
No plug-in printers are configured.
 
Diagnose completed...



More information on Troubleshooting,How-To's and Support is available on http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html
```

The first thing that seems odd is that it is [reported that hplip-gui on Ubuntu 20.04 is compiled against qt5](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/1878974).  Also many of these packages reported missing/incompatible are already installed (via apt).

Before my fresh install, I tried `apt purge` to get rid of everything hplip and reinstalled them, never with any success.  I tried this several times and eventually somehow broke my system which lead to the fresh installation.

I am not sure what to do from here to get hplip working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From hplip's launchpad site I have found a solution which worked for me. It is post #7 in [this thread](https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/691141). The problem I describe in the question is caused by Ubuntu 20.04 using python3 with reduced support for python2.  If /usr/bin/python links to a python 2 version then running hplip-3.20.**.run will have the reported problems trying and failing to install the necessary python components.

To diagnose this problem, run

`python --version`

if you get a version with leading digit 2 then the fix is as follows

```
sudo unlink /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.* /usr/bin/python
```

where python3.* is whichever version of python3 you have installed.  You can find this out by running

`ls /usr/bin/python*`

Once I did this then running

`sh hplip-3.20.**.run`

worked fine

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Download the file to ~/Dowloads

https://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/hplip/3.20.6/hplip-3.20.6.run/download?use_mirror=nchc

Open a terminal and remove the previously installed version:

```
sudo apt remove hplip*
```

Cd to the location where the installer was downloaded.

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

To install run this command:

```
sh hplip-3.20.6.run
```

Select the install mode Automatic, enter an a

Ensure the installer detected the correct Linux distribution.

Enter Your root/Superuser User Password.

The installer will now detect what dependencies your system will need to install before installing HPLIP

If your system is missing any dependencies they are now downloaded and installed.

./configure prepares HPLIP for install as well as your system is verified to have all the required dependencies for HPLIP.

'make' is then executed. Make compiles ("builds") HPLIP for your system.

'make install' is the actual install procedure, this step is where HPLIP is actually being installed to your system.

Use 'hp-setup' to configure your printer.

The first step is to select the printer connection type.

Next the setup tool will display printers detected.

Select the PPD file to be Used for Your printer, usually you will want to select the recommended PPD file.

Click "AddPrinter" to complete the printer setup process.

Comment: This almost worked.  The uninstall and installation via hplip-3.20.6.run worked until the setting up the printer.  At that point I had the same error:`error:  Printer queue setup failed.   Error : successful-ok-ignored-or-substituted-attributes`.  Although the installer exited at that point, all the components were installed and so I ran `hp-setup` with `sudo` and that worked.

Comment: I am confused why the apt version of hplip is not installing properly though. Any ideas?

Comment: This worked for me, although installation of the hplip-xxxxx-plugin.run coughed.  I needed to download it from https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/plugins and install it manually.  Xsane worked flawlessly after that.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install python3 and all the toolkits.

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python3-pyqt5
sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5
sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python3-notify
```

Then when you run `hplip` respond "no" to the failed install of the old python.

```
sh hplip-3.20.9.run
```

and finally:

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module
```

which seems to be necessary, although I don't know why.
Delete your printer then reinstall, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to update the symlink manually (as brett stevens suggested), you can use `python-is-python3`:

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

then reinstall hplip.